# Error while converting and updating images to AWS s3 using sails.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sails.js, graphicsmagick, aws-cli

I'm trying to convert and upload 1000+ images to aws s3 using sails.js

I'm fetching images using aws-cli via url and after processing using graphicsmagick uploading back to bucket.

After some times i'm getting error mentioned below

```
{"level":"error",
"message":"Error uploading data:  RequestTimeTooSkewed: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
at Request.extractError (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:327:35)
at Request.callListeners (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at Request.emit (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:595:14)
at Request.transition (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:21:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:37:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:597:12)
at Request.callListeners (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
at Request.emit (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:595:14)
at Request.transition (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:21:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/home/images/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:37:9) { [RequestTimeTooSkewed: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.]
message: 'The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.',
code: 'RequestTimeTooSkewed',
region: null,
time: Thu Nov 12 2015 16:05:21 GMT+0000 (UTC),
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 30 }",
"timestamp":"2015-11-12T16:05:21.626Z"}
```

I'm running this code on aws ec2 
with 200GB disk space in home directory

```
$ free -m

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3951        444       3507          5         20        290
-/+ buffers/cache:        132       3819
Swap:            0          0          0


$ free mem

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3951        444       3507          5         20        290
-/+ buffers/cache:        132       3819
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Any suggestion is appreciable .

Thanks